# Display list of items in just two row

Tags: blazor, bootstrap-5, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

In Blazor WASM I want to display list of items in just two row, lets say the list contain 15 item, I want each row show 5 items and with next/previous button you can access to the other 5 items

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a blazor component `ItemList`:

```
@using System.Linq

<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in itemList.Skip(currentChunk * chunkSize).Take(chunkSize)) {
        <div class="col-2">@item</div>
    }
</div>

<button @onclick="() => currentChunk--" disabled="@(currentChunk == 0 ? true: false)">Previous</button>
<button @onclick="() => currentChunk++" disabled="@(currentChunk >= itemList.Count() / chunkSize - 1 ? true: false)">Next</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<string> itemList { get; set; }

    int chunkSize = 5;
    int currentChunk = 0;
}
```

Then you can use like this:

```
@page "/"

<ItemList itemList="@myItemList" />

@code {
    List<string> myItemList= new List<string>()
        {
            "item1",
            "item2",
            "item3",
            "item4",
            "item5",
            "item6",
            "item7",
            "item8",
            "item9",
            "item10"
        };
}
```

[Fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/p0u5twst)